# How to forward one url to 404-error page on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

my mvc application is using folowing urls:

`/Content/
/Content/style.css
/Content/image.png`

I want to create forward for url `/Content/` it should be forwarded to 404 error. All other urls should work. How to do it?

I tried following solution, but it forwards all files from /Content/ to 404 error page, but I want just main directory to be blocked.

Web.config:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      ...
      <add name="hideDirectoryContent" verb="*" path="Content" type=" NameSspace.NoAccessHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

NoAccesHandler.cs:

```
public class NoAccessHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this you just need to create a controller as below (tested on mvc 4)

```
public class ContentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Content
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found");
    }
}
```

and in your RoutesCollection use

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

hope this helps

Comment: but if other paths like `/Content/file1.jpg` are still working?